# Expand Range After Find Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to expand the found range to enter a value into multiple cells within the row and cannot find the appropriate solution.

```
Dim C as Range
Dim SrchRng    
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("W1", ActiveSheet.Range("W65536").End(xlUp))
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("X", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Value = "X"
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

In this example, the single cell found will be changed to "X".  I'd like to expand that to multiple cells within that row so "X" appears in columns T through W of the found row.

Comment: `c.Offset(,-3).resize(1,4).Value = "X"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
If Not c Is Nothing Then Range("T:W").Rows(c.Row).Value = "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
If Not c Is Nothing Then 
  c.Value = "x"
  ActiveSheet.Range("T" & c.Row & ":W" & c.Row) = "x"
End If
```